# program to traverse directory structure in python

Tags: python, scripting, operating-system

I need to create a program in which I have been given a directory path, in that directory there can be n number of tree type directory structure, and in any directory there can be any number of .py File. Some files were executed are some dnt. So I need to create a script in python that only run those files which are not executed till now. Can someone please suggest the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at `os.walk()`.

```
import os

directory = '/tmp'
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
    # Do something with dirpath, dirnames, and filenames.
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to use `os.walk` and to compose complete paths using `os.path.join`:

```
import os
import os.path

def find_all_files(directory):
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            yield fullpath

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for fullpath in find_all_files('/tmp'):
        print(fullpath)
```

In my experience, `dirnames` return value of `os.walk` is rarely used, so I omitted it with `_`.

As for your question about files being executed or not -- I don't get it. Please explain.